# Unable to say "invalid entry" to my code, always results in error with int

Tags: python

So this is what I am struggling with on my assignment...

"You are to account for invalid input. Drivers must be between the ages of 16 and 105. Number of traffic violations cannot be less than 0. Display only the message “Invalid Entry” in either case"

I can get the age part right but for the life of me I cannot get the number of violations to not work... can anyone assist?

**Basically what I am needing is I need:**

```
def Invalid_Entry():
    if Violation == float or Violation == str and Violation == int:
    print("Invalid Entry")
```

**to work... this is my issue. The rest of the code works exactly as it needs to work. However, I need it so when the user enters a number for number of violations it can only be a whole number and a numeric item, no "terms", if that makes sense.**

```
Name = input("What is the customers name? ")

Age = int(input("What is the age of the customer? "))

Violations = int(input("How many violations does the customer have? "))



def main():
    Violation = Number_Violations(Violations)
    Price =  Premium()
    Invalid = Invalid_Entry()

    if Age < 16 or Age >= 106:
        print("Invalid Entry")
    else:
        print(Name, "as a ", Violation, "risk driver, your insurance will cost 
     ", Price)


def Number_Violations(Violations):
    if Violations >= 4:
        return "High"
    elif Violations == 0:
        return "None"
    elif Violations == 1:
        return "Low"
    elif Violations == 2 or 3:
        return "Moderate"
    else:
        Violations != 0
        return "invalid Entry"
    return Violations

def Premium():

    if Violations >= 4 and Age >= 25:
        return "$410.00"
    elif Violations >= 4 and Age < 25:
        return "480.00"
    elif Violations == 3 and Age >= 25:
        return "390.00"
    elif Violations == 3 and Age < 25:
        return "450.00"
    elif Violations == 2 and Age >= 25:
        return "365.00"
    elif Violations == 2 and Age < 25:
        return "405.00"
    elif Violations == 1 and Age >= 25:
        return "315.00"
    elif Violations == 1 and Age < 25: 
        return "$380.00"
    elif Violations == 0 and Age >= 25:
        return "275.00"
    else:
        return "$325"

def Invalid_Entry():
    if Violation == float or Violation == str and Violation == int:
        print("Invalid Entry")


main()
```

Comment: Could you have a look at the indent of the code you have provided. I am guessing it is not as intended in several places. Could you also give an example of input that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I went ahead and fixed your indents, might double check them to make sure they match your file as well.

Comment: The indentation is correct in the code itself in my visual studio, stackOverflow kinda set it this way for me. The actual code itself runs, it does everything I need it to do.

Comment: Did the answer below fix you data verification error? Or it just compiles with no errors still? If it is not working in the way you would like please help us by gibing an example input and how you expect it to work.

Comment: Zack, I updated the file with bold of what I am needing. While the code below works as well, it wasn't causing an issue with my code. The code itself runs perfectly fine, except for the one area I am missing. I hope what I put in bold makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check both age and number of traffic violations at the beginning of the program, and exit if conditions are not satisfied:

```
if (Age < 16 or Age >= 106 or Violations<0):
    print("Invalid Entry")
    exit()
```

For that solution you will need to import exit function before executing it:

```
from sys import exit
```

*EDIT. Following our comments, here is a code that should work:

```
from sys import exit

Name = input("What is the customers name? ")

# enter age and violations number and check type and value
try:
    Age = int(input("What is the age of the customer? "))
    Violations = int((input("How many violations does the customer have? ")))
except ValueError:
    exit('invalid entry')
if (Violations<0 or Age not in range(16,107)):
    exit('invalid entry')


def main(name, age,violations):
    driver_risk = Number_violations(violations)
    price =  Premium(violations,age)
    print("{} as a {} risk driver, your insurance will cost {}".format(name, driver_risk, price))


def Number_violations(violations):
    if violations == 0:
        return "None"
    elif violations == 1:
        return "Low"
    elif violations in [2,3]:
        return "Moderate"
    else:
        return "High"


def Premium(violations,age):
    if violations >= 4 and age >= 25:
        return "$410.00"
    elif violations >= 4 and age < 25:
        return "480.00"
    elif violations == 3 and age >= 25:
        return "390.00"
    elif violations == 3 and age < 25:
        return "450.00"
    elif violations == 2 and age >= 25:
        return "365.00"
    elif violations == 2 and age < 25:
        return "405.00"
    elif violations == 1 and age >= 25:
        return "315.00"
    elif violations == 1 and age < 25: 
        return "$380.00"
    elif violations == 0 and age >= 25:
        return "275.00"
    else:
        return "$325"


main(Name,Age,Violations)
```

Comment: When I do this and enter, let's say .3 as my number of violations it breaks the code saying that it has to be a base of 10 (to go along with it asking for an int)

Comment: The exact error from my Visual Studio is: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.3'"

Comment: This is because inputs are strings and python cannot convert string to int.You need to first convert it into a float:
Violations = int(float(input("How many violations does the customer have? ")))

Comment: I tried that one as well. The issue with that is the user can now enter a decimal number, let's say "0.3" and the program would still give them a quote. I need it so the program will only give a quote if the number is a whole number. So any decimal numbers or terms such as None, etc, will result in "Invalid Entry"

Comment: then you can for instance use exception handling:

`try:
    Age = int(input("What is the age of the customer? "))
    Violations = int((input("How many violations does the customer have? ")))
except ValueError:
    exit('invalid entry')`

This will exit if age or violation are not integers. Then you can check their values with the previous conditions:
`if (Age < 16 or Age >= 106 or Violations<0):
    exit("Invalid Entry")`

Comment: I do apologize, I am trying this, but it says the except is not valid, it has the red line under it

Comment: Hello Anna, I don't know what the red line stands for. I will post a code example in an edit to my answer that seems to do what I understand you are looking for. I would recommend you pass variables to your fonctions as arguments rather than directly using their value. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This line of code doesn't do what you expect:

```
elif Violations == 2 or 3:
```

It should be this:

```
elif Violations in [2, 3]:
```